# Search and replace values in a text tile based on existence of a third value

Tags: search, text, replace

We have about a thousand machining files we need to update and I know in the past I have used a search and replace tool of some sort to do conditional searches.   In this case, if the file contains a specific string, we need to find and replace two other values in that text file.

IE
If the file contains 'TNO="128"' then find and replace 'S_A="19000"' with 'S_A="13000"', and find and replace 'F_="22"' with 'F_="18"'.  Continue to next file containing 'TNO="128"' and repeat

I thought at one time I had an actual tool that did this (many years ago I am sure) but I am open to ideas on what could work.

Tried doing this with NPP but was unable to find an option to filter the results.   Looked at some JS ideas, but they didn't match up to the weirdness I am trying to solve.  I have not used regex (not sure what it is)

Answer (score 0):

A Notepad++ approach using regular expressions might look like:

```
Find:    ^(?=.*TNO="128")(.*)S_A="19000"
Replace: $1S_A="13000"
```

Run this regex replacement in dot all mode.

This regex says to match:

- `^` from the start of the file
- `(?=.*TNO="128")` assert that `TNO="128"` occurs somewhere in the file
- `(.*)` match and capture in `$1` all content until reaching
- `S_A="19000"` match target text

Then we replace with the intended text.

### Demo